# How do I separate the logic for this sumatory statement?

Tags: javascript

say I have the following:

[image]

At the moment, when the two input fields are updated they rely on each other to update the final amount. How do I make it so that even if one field is null the grand total still gets updated?

(rightsTotal will never be null)

```
function calculateTotal() {
     var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('travelField').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('giftField').value) + rightsTotal; 
     document.getElementById("grandTotal").innerHTML = '£' + number1 ;   
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no conditional statement. I update your post.

Comment: Side note: when using `parseInt`, you [should always specify a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` will return `NaN` (not a number) if your input is empty (i.e. an empty String `""`).

You could use `parseInt` in combination with an `||` (or) expression and return `0` if your value is not a Number:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var travelField = parseInt(document.getElementById('travelField').value) || 0;
    var giftField = parseInt(document.getElementById('giftField').value) || 0

    var number1 = travelField + giftField + rightsTotal;

    document.getElementById("grandTotal").innerHTML = '£' + number1 ;   
 }
```

Comment: Not exactly. In the way that you put `Math.round()` it's true, but without it, if is not a number, `Number()` function can return `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the result of parseInt is a number. `isNan()` returns true when the result is not a number, so we can use the ternary operator to provide 0 instead of NaN.

```
var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('travelField').value);
var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('giftField').value);

var result = (isNan(number1) ? 0 : number1) + (isNan(number2) ? 0 : number2) + rightsTotal
```

Comment: I upvote you, but an explanation is required. Put only code is not a good answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateTotal() {
     var number1 = (isNan(parseInt(document.getElementById('travelField').value))) ? 0 : parseInt(document.getElementById('travelField').value); // set  value to 0 if nothing present in the textfield
     var number2 = (isNan(parseInt(document.getElementById('giftField').value))) ? 0 : parseInt(document.getElementById('giftField').value); // set  value to 0 if nothing present in the textfield

     var total = number1 + number2 + rightsTotal;
     document.getElementById("grandTotal").innerHTML = '£' + total ;   
 }
```